# Why does STM32 not interrupt?

Tags: c++, c, timer, stm32

I am writing a simple program for the microcontroller STM32F407 disk drives. I have already learned how to use timers to delay the execution of a program, but what if I need to start a timer regardless of the main program.
I try to do everything according to the technical documentation, but the timer overflow interrupt does not work.
Thanks for the answer anyway!

```
    #include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stdbool.h"

void clock_perif ();
void init_HSE ();
void init_GPIOD ();
void init_TIM6(int time);


#define ledTime 1

int main(void){
    init_HSE ();




    __enable_irq ();
    //NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM6_DAC_IRQn);
    NVIC->ISER[1] = 0x400000;

    clock_perif ();

    init_GPIOD ();
    init_TIM6 (ledTime);



    while (1){
    }

}


/*
init RCC
*/

void clock_perif (){
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIODEN;
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM6EN;
    asm("NOP");
    asm("NOP");
    asm("NOP");
    asm("NOP");
    asm("NOP");
    asm("NOP");
}


/*
Activate external qarzt
*/

void init_HSE (){
     RCC->CR = RCC_CR_HSEON;
   while (!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSERDY));
   RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_0;
   while (!(RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS_0));
   RCC->CFGR &= ~ RCC_CFGR_HPRE_3 | RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_2 | RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_2;
}


/*
Activate GPIOs
*/

void init_GPIOD (){
    GPIOD->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE15_0 | GPIO_MODER_MODE14_0 | GPIO_MODER_MODE13_0 | GPIO_MODER_MODE12_0;
    GPIOD->PUPDR |= GPIO_PUPDR_PUPD15_1 | GPIO_PUPDR_PUPD14_1 | GPIO_PUPDR_PUPD13_1 | GPIO_PUPDR_PUPD13_1;
}


/*
Timer 6
*/
void init_TIM6(int time){   
    TIM6->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_URS | TIM_CR1_UDIS;
    TIM6->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UIE;
    TIM6->CNT = 0;
    TIM6->PSC = 7900;
    TIM6->ARR = 1;
    TIM6->EGR = 1;
    TIM6->SR = 0;
    TIM6->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
}


//Interrupts!
void TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler (){
    GPIOD->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS15 | GPIO_BSRR_BS14 | GPIO_BSRR_BS13 | GPIO_BSRR_BS12;
}
```

I am new to microcontroller programming and I still have problems

Comment: do not use magic numbers. It is waste of our time to guess the bits beaning.

Comment: Are you correctly replacing the timer ISR, the weak symbol name is `TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler`? An ISR are supposed to be a naked function, if you're using GCC it should be `void __attribute__ (( naked ))  TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler (void) {`

Comment: @Frankie_C Where have you read the *naked* requirement? Neither the STM32Cube code nor the code generated by STM32CubeMX use this attribute. So I very much doubt it.

Comment: @Codo, you're right, isn't a requirement. I normally use it because I keep my ISR code as simple and short as possible.

Comment: I guess you have to break down the problem a little as several things are involved. Does the timer tick while the programs runs? Have your read TIM6->CNR? It updates?

Answer (score 0):

You disable the Update Event generation by setting the bit `TIM_CR1_UDIS`. Consequently no interrupt is generated.